Sampling orthogonal matrices from Haar-random unitary group
I would like to know the probability of sampling orthogonal matrices $O \in O(d)$ from Haar-random unitary group $U(d)$. The probability may be close to zero since orthogonal matrices are "sparse" in the unitary group. I would like to quantify this "sparseness" in Haar measure. How to show that it is almost impossible to sample orthogonal matrices from Haar-random unitary group, or show the size of orthogonal group is infinitely smaller than of unitary group?

It's zero. In general Haar measure on a Lie group of dimension $n$ is zero on submanifolds of dimension less than $n$, generalizing the familiar case of Euclidean spaces.

indeed, for example, for $d=1$ you ask for the probability that you land on precisely the point $(0,1)$ when you randomly and uniformly pick a point on the unit circle... for a nonzero probability you will want to allow for a certain tolerance.

Thank you for your answers!! That help a lot. I am working on quantum information and I may not be very familiar with Lie group. Could you provide some materials about these?
